# Why are there different unequal limits for this functor?

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

From Mac Lane's category theory:

Why is theorem $2$ true?  How can the equalizer be the limit of $F: J \rightarrow C$ when it was just proven in the last sentence of theorem $1$ that $\mu : d \dot\rightarrow F$ is the limiting cone and the two cones are not equal?

---

[image]

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+the

Comment: @DerekElkins I'm not quite sure I see the connection, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you read the remainder of the sentence, it states how to build a cone of the appropriate shape from the equalizer. And you are right, my comment isn't relevant as they are exactly equal by definition. It is more relevant to the fact that "the" limit of $F:J\to C$ doesn't necessarily *have to* equal this cone. At any rate, Theorem 2 is just pointing out that the proof of the *existence* of a limit, which is all that Theorem 1 claims, actually gives us a specific construction. Theorem 1 states that there is a limit; Theorem 2 states what that limit is.

Comment: @DerekElkins But what about the statement "the limit of $F: J \rightarrow C$ is the equalizer"?  The equalizer can't be a limit of $F$ because it's not a universal arrow $\Delta d \dot \rightarrow (F: J \rightarrow C)$.  So is that an incorrect statement?

Comment: The *object part* of the equalizer, i.e. the apex of the limiting cone for the diagram representing the equalizer, is the object part of the limit for $F$. It might have been slightly more precise to say "the limiting cone of $F:J\to C$ *is induced by* the equalizer $e$...", but as the details are spelled out *in the very same sentence* I'm willing give Mac Lane a pass on this one.